# How use os.popen() or os.system() method in python 2.7 for executing a winscp command?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import os

WINSCP = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com' # the path of winscp in my system
command = "winscp /console /script=SFTP.txt /parameter /opt/outgo/aftp/20161222.zip.pgp C:\Users\Abh\Desktop\\"
stdin, stdout = os.popen2(WINSCP + command)
```

I am trying to execute this winscp command using popen function of os module to do sftp in client system. However this code is not working as I expect it to. Can you please tell me what is the correct way of doing so, as I am doing it wrong i believe.

This script I am writing for python 2.7 interpreter on windows.

Comment: @cdarke I forgot to put the command string in quotes. Thanks for correction.

Comment: Your final `\"` is an issue, because python thinks you are escaping the quotes.  Use `\\\`.

Comment: @cdarke can you please correct me in my usage of popen for accomplishing my purpose?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what your problem is?  I don't use Windows and am not familiar with `winscp`.  Apart from the string issues I pointed out and you have corrected, the python looks fine as far as it goes, but you are not writing to `stdin` or reading from `stdout`.  (BTW, you are using `popen2`, not `popen`).

Comment: The problem is that when I execute this command using either popen() or popen2() function, I don't get the file that I was trying to fetch from the clients machine using SFTP on my machine.

Comment: Where are you reading/writing the pipes?

Comment: Try printing out the concatenation of your two strings, and see if it makes any sense as a command.  You're trying to run a program named "WinSCP.comwinscp"

Comment: Also, you need double quotes around the entire pathname due to the space in "Program Files".

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import time

year = time.strftime("%Y", time.localtime())
month = time.strftime("%m", time.localtime())
day = int(time.strftime("%d", time.localtime()))-1
WINSCP =r'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinSCP\\WinSCP.com"'
command = WINSCP + " /console /script=SFTP.txt /parameter /opt/outgoing/ttaftp/" + str(year) + str(month) + str(day) +\
       ".zip.pgp C:\\Users\\m\\Desktop\\"
os.system(command)
```

This script helped me to execute the winscp command and get the desired result.